# Why is this simple exam document couldn't be compiled?

Tags: exam

I am learning how to type an exam under the exam documentclass, below is how I typed it, but it couldn't be compiled and I have no clue why.

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,a4paper]{exam}  

\begin{questions}  
\question Why is there air?  
\question What if there were no air?  
\end{questions}
```

I think there shouldn't be any mistake and I have checked that I have the exam.cls.
Many thanks for any help, I will really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with all `LaTeX` documents, you need to include `\begin{document}...\end{document}` as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,a4paper]{exam}  

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}  
\question Why is there air?  
\question What if there were no air?  
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I learned a very important and basic knowledge.